# Google Analytics Goal Special URL Parameters based on {{page URL}} event

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my Google Tag Manager Events, I am tracking Downloads use `{{Page URL}}` as the action.  However, in my Analytics Goals, I'd like to use an event to track downloads of a SPECIFIC PAGE. So,

> Category - Download, Action - Specific Page URL, Label - Specific Audience.

How do I use a SPECIFIC page URL in my Google Analytics goals to work off the event tracking I have that tracks all pages?

Comment: Here is another example.  What parameters would one use to make the {{formName}} = a specific form name in Analytics Event Goals? https://www.clickinsight.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Create-GA-event-tag-with-formName-variable-1.png

Answer (score 1):

You wanna see how many downloads happened on certain page. I would suggest that you update your tracking a bit.  You should track your downloadable links, buttons, etc. with a specific tag in which the label will be `{{Page Path}}` or `{{Page URL}}`.

In a configuration like this, you will get an exact name of the file downloaded as well as on which page that happened.

Comment: On this i could only add that you should enable built in variable {{Click Text}} and set that one on label. He get the page he get the file, that is all